# Formula for determining dimensions of interior divs based on dimensions of exterior div?

Tags: math, html, pixel

Let's say I have a container div that is 765px wide by 530px high.

I want to dynamically fill as much of that div with 30 smaller divs. Since the container div is a rectangle, the filling divs should be a rectangle as well. Basically, I don't want squares, I want to fill the space.

What is the formula?

Thanks!

Comment: What are dimensions of 30 smaller divs?

Comment: That's the formula I need. How big should those 30 divs be to fill that main space?

Comment: 30 divs should all have equal size?

Comment: Yes. I want to fill the space with divs like you would a checkerboard. Except my board isn't square.

Comment: If my board is a rectangle, my tiles should be rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

With 30 you can make a grid of 5 by 6, so divide the height with 6 and width by 5, or height by 5 and width by 6. If the divs have to have integers sizes you wont be able to fill the width or height with 6 though, since neither is divisible by 6...

Answer (score 0):

So to find the width and height of each piece where N is the number of pieces you have (30 in this case), H is the height of the box to fill (530 in this case) and W is the width of the box to fill (765 in this case)...

```
eachPieceWidth = floor(W/ceil(sqrt(N)))
eachPieceHeight = floor(H/(N/ceil(sqrt(N)))
```

leads to...

```
eachPieceWidth = floor(765/ceil(sqrt(30)))
eachPieceHeight = floor(530/(30/ceil(sqrt(30)))
```

leads to...

```
eachPieceWidth = 127
eachPieceHeight = 106
```

Comment: That formula works if you assume the outer dimensions are close to square. However, I elaborated a bit to make the actual sub-divs themselves as close to square as possible, which is probably more important. For example if you had a box that was 40x800 and you wanted to fill it with 20 divs, you would probably want a 1x20 grid, not a 4x5 grid.

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can expand on your problem for you a bit.

You have a container with width `w` and height `h`, and you want to fill it with `n` equal-sized rectangles. You want to find `x`, `y`, such that `x * y = n`, but you want `w/x` to be approximately equal to `h/y` so that your small rectangles are as close to square as possible (because if they are `1xn` slices, that would probably be pretty useless) and you want them to be aesthetically pleasing.

First, if `n` is a prime number, you are going to either need to relax your assumptions a bit or you will end up with a bunch of thin slices. Otherwise, I would iterate through all the factors of `n`, and for each factor `x` compute `y=n/x` and then compute `w/x` and `h/y`. Then pick the pair where `|w/x - h/y|` is smallest, and you'll have the most 'square` divs that you can fit in a grid that container.

In your case. `w`=765 and `h`=530. The factors of 30 are 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10, 15, 30. We consider the following pairs, which would result in the following div sizes (rounded down):

- (1, 30) - (765, 17)
- (2, 15) - (382, 35)
- (3, 10) - (255, 53)
- (5, 6) - (153, 88)
- (6, 5) - (127, 106)
- (10, 3) - (76, 176)
- (15, 2) - (51, 265)
- (30, 1) - (25, 530)

In this case the smallest difference with the pair `(127, 106)` is the same you came up using your formula, but you can imagine that it would not be the case if you had a long and thin container, or for some reason you preferred to have child divs with a different aspect ratio that was not as square. In that case you would pick the division that is most appropriate.